# Possible pitfalls/accuracy issues using a weighted average of a median

Tags: median, weighted

I am trying to aggregate data for testing for multiple data sets. It is unrealistic to load the entire data set (which is composed of multiple subsets of varying length) into memory to calculate a median. As one solution to my problem, I thought I could find the median of each subset of data, along with the sample size, and aggregate it into a weighted average by doing something like

(x_1(n_1) + x_2(n_2))/n

were x is the median and n is the data set size.

This is essentially taking a weighted average of medians. Is there a risk that taking the weighted average of medians will be far off from the actual median of the data set?

I am not a mathematician by trade so I appreciate the help. ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "far off" and the nature of your data

- If subsets of the data are nearly symmetrical
  and do not have long tails in either direction, then their means and medians will not be much
  different, and your method will give something like
  an ordinary weighted average (of means).
- However, if some subsets are
  markedly skewed or long-tailed, as in the example below, then
  your weighted median might be relatively "far" from the median
  of the whole sample.

Fictitious data:

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rexp(20, 1/5)    # right-skewed
x2 = rt(10, 4)        # long tailed
x3 = rnorm(30, 20, 3)
x = c(x1, x2, x3)     # combined sample
median(x)
[1] 15.35097          # actual sample median
(20*median(x1) + 10*median(x2) + 30*median(x3))/(20+10+30) 
[1] 11.1669           # weighted sample median

boxplot(x1,x2,x3, varwidth=T)
 abline(h = 11.17, col="red")
 abline(h = 15.35, col="green2")
```

In the figure below the horizontal green line
is the median of the sample, and the red line
is your weighted median.

[image]

Comment: This is financial data so it is definitely not normally distributed, lots of long tail events. Thank you for your answer and demonstration - very helpful.